Is the minimum energy pathway a geodesic in the potential energy surface?
I just finished NEB-TS calculation using Orca 4.2.1. One of the output file is the minimum energy pathway (MEP) data. Am I correct to interpret the MEP as the geodesic (path of minimum length) on the Potential Energy Surface (PES)? 
I tried to find some reference on this, but cannot find any.

The easiest way doesn't have to be the shortest.

True, but considering we're looking for the MEP, we are technically looking for saddle point on the PES. And for some reason, it appears to me that in a given surface, the pathway that goes through a saddle point between 2 minimal is usually a geodesic.
